# How to get symbols between two input boxes using ionic 2?

Tags: html, ionic2

I am new to ionic 2,I wanted to get the special symbols(/) between the two input text boxes using ionic.
Below is the screen what actually want:

[image]

below is my code what i had tried:

```
<div padding>Credit Card</div>
<hr>
<ion-item   class="Credit">
<ion-input  type="number"
            id="Credit cardnumber"
            placeholder="Credit Card number"
            class="form-control"
            pattern="[0-9]{10}"></ion-input>
<ion-icon name="your_icon_name" item-right primary></ion-icon>
</ion-item>

<ion-row>
<ion-item   class="month">
<ion-input  type="number"
            placeholder="MM"
            pattern="[0-9]{2}"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<span class="symbol">/</span> 
<ion-item   class="year">
<ion-input   type="number"
            placeholder="YY"
            pattern="[0-9]{2}"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item   class="cvv">
<ion-input   type="password"
            placeholder="CVV"
            pattern="[0-9]{3}"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: what output are you getting?

Comment: I divided the row into 3 different blocks and then i had applied css but it is changing its position from one mobile to another mobile and also (/) should display between month and year,i am not getting symbol

Comment: html may require escape character.. try '\/' (backslash and then forward slash)

Comment: in <span> i had tried but it is not coming...

Comment: Try  `&#47;`  from [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html)

Comment: @Suraj Rao its not working

Comment: for me / is printed directly.. what is your encoding in index.html

Comment: <span class="symbol">/</span>  i am using these tag is these tag but symbol is not displaying...